# Who has Docker working (pi 4b)? What OS did you use?

Tags: pi-4, driver, operating-systems, docker

First off I am running berryboot on the sd of my raspberry pi 4b so I can load/run raspbian desktop OS off a 480gb SSD. I hate not have running out of storage ever (this works fine). Issues:

Docker will not install on my raspberry pi 4 running Raspbian OS without using the aufs as it's storage driver. I have tried 5 different ways reformatting after each try so any docker stuff is gone. None one seems to be able to tell how to either switch storage drivers for the pi (docker documentation on this failed probably because it was for regular computer + os).

Aufs is a big problem because it is being depreciated and because I can't run anything with aufs as a storage driver apparently because the deamon always seems to fail to mount it appropriately.

So I give up on Raspbian and am dreading the possible errors for the other OS's so I would really like to know who has Docker running appropriately for 2020 fresh stable installs before I throw my raspberry pi at the wall in frustration (not throwing anything just feel like it).

Thank you community and stay safe.

Comment: Yes, I tried Docker on R4B buster and found everything OK - but I am ***NOT using ausf***: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104989/docker-running-on-rpizw-does-everything-but-actually-running-container-sigsegv. Cheers.

Comment: I don't want to use aufs. I don't get a choice. Please how can I switch.

Comment: Well, buster does not like ausf, and asuf only likes jessie. So "you can't have your cake and eat it too".  When switching to buster, I also very sadly gave up a couple of my favourite things: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IagRZBvLtwwhen.

Comment: Thanks for the laugh I needed it bad.

Comment: Your are welcome. Have a great locking down day: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGtf9QfITQw. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here : https://github.com/joweisberg/rpi-docker-owncloud
Everything is automatically installed on Ubuntu with docker, docker-compose, glances, traefik owncloud, muximux, and then you can add everything you want

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Since you are new here, you might find it useful to take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out how things work. "Link only" answers are discouraged as if the link breaks the answer will become useless. I notice you appear to have linked to your GitHub. This is fine but [you must disclose your affiliation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).